# Encoding ASP Clássico

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp

Tenho uma aplicação em `.asp` e estava tendo problemas com caracteres especiais, eles eram impressos em tela de uma forma totalmente desconfigurada.

Para solucionar o problema, apliquei:

```
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"
Response.CodePage = 28591
```

Porém agora os mesmos estão sendo impressos em tela como �.

Obs: Em minha aplicação, existe uma mescla de `.asp` e .`aspx`

Comment: O seu banco de dados é UTF8?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Me perdoe a pergunta mas, como posso verificar isso ?

Comment: Foi você que fez o banco ou foi outra pessoa é SQLServer2008? Tem como visualizar a estrutura? Ou você não usa banco?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Foi outra pessoa mas tenho acesso de SA

Comment: Esses caracteres `�` são impressos de um view populado por um banco ou é algo escrito manualmente no arquivo .aspx?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ambos

Comment: Você salvou os arquivos como utf8 ou como ansi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Codifique sempre em UTF-8 nunca em ANSI.**

**Código ASP Classic:**

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8
```

Se quiser o código em HTML seria:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

**Porque em UTF-8?**
Porque é muito mais natural escrevemos assim a palavra "*`ação`*" do que "*`a&ccedil;&atilde;o`*"
Além de ser a forma recomendada para language com acentos.

---

As vezes não basta colocar o código acima se o encoding do cabeçalho do arquivo estiver como ANSI, para isso faça:

Abre o arquivo .ASP no bloco de notas.
Manda "salvar como..." coloque a opção utf-8

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Quando mexo em páginas ASP verifico duas coisas: a formatação do script (página .asp - se está com ANSI, UTF...) e a codificação do script (response.charset). Uso para ambas configurações UTF-8.